# How to filter select box options by value?

Tags: jquery

I have this select box with options:

```
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Using jQuery, how can I filter this select box so that it only shows the options with values < `3`.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: $('#mySelect :not(option[value=3])').hide()

Answer (score 3):

There can be many ways to achieve your goal, for example:

```
// filter options by hiding all values >= 3
$('#mySelect option').filter(function(v, el) { return $(el).val() >= 3; }).hide();
// optional: find first visible option and set it as a value
$('#mySelect').val( $('#mySelect option:visible').eq(0).val() );
```

Comment: Just handle the assigning of `#mySelect` value with the first visible child and i'm upvoting :) (In case he will change it to < 3 or any other possibility which value `1` isn't included.

Comment: I've changed the operator from `> 3` to `>= 3`, since you've asked for hiding all options `< 3`. Here is your example at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/20e5rhfk/)